# A mixtilinear tangency

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let ABC be a triangle with incircle $\gamma$ and circumcircle $\Gamma$. Let $\Omega$ be the circle tangent to rays $AB, AC,$ and to $\Gamma$ externally, and let $A^{\prime}$ be the tangency point of $\Omega$ with $\Gamma$. Let the tangents from $A^{\prime}$ to $\gamma$ intersect $\Gamma$ again at $B^{\prime}$ and $C^{\prime}$. Finally, let $X$ be the tangency
point of the chord $B^{\prime}C^{\prime}$ with $\gamma$. Prove that the circumcircle of triangle $BXC$ is tangent to $\gamma$.

This is something I found from geogebra. Is there a proof of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does _mixtillinear_ mean? Top Google results point to this question.

Comment: $\Omega$ is known as the $A$-mixtillinear incircle. The circle touching the circumcircle internally, and two of the sides of the triangle is called the mixtillinear circle. Now depending on the vertices the name changes. The title may mislead you, but everything required to prove, is mentioned in the problem. I suppose I have cleared up your query a bit @Thisismuchhealthier.

Comment: The proper spelling is *mixtilinear* (one "l"), for which web-search results are plentiful. See, eg, Cut the Knot articles [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/MixtilinearConcurrence.shtml) and [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/MixtilinearConstruction.shtml), as well as MathWorld entries [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MixtilinearIncircles.html), [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MixtilinearCircle.html), and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MixtilinearTriangle.html). An American Mathematical Monthly article is [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589751).

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I didn't know. Anyways, I hope it is more readable now.